# Case insesitive query with Springboot CRUD Repository

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

Values in Room_Entity table is hardcoded and Room_Status values are in uppercase . I want my search to be case insensitive. Here is my query. I am using upper but getting error

```
@Query(value = "SELECT TOP 1 r.ROOM_ID  FROM ROOM_ENTITY r WHERE r.ROOM_STATUS ='AVAILABLE'  AND r.ROOM_TYPE =:upper(roomType)", nativeQuery = true)
int findRoom(@Param("roomType") String roomType);
```

Comment: `upper(:roomType)`

Comment: But I'd consider a case insensitive collation instead.

Comment: Thank you , it worked. I will try  case insensitive collation.

Comment: @jarlh Please add this as the answer. Thank you

Comment: Do you confirm the room_type always stores value with uppercase ? otherwise you need upper in both side .

Comment: Yes, room_type always stores value with uppercase. I have hardcoded values in Room_Entity table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
AND r.ROOM_TYPE = upper(:roomType)
```

But I'd consider using a case insensitive collation for the ROOM_TYPE column.